# IE 10 not event not firing bind() or on() using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('body').unload(function () {

});
$('body').on("beforeunload", function () {

  //if true Means Logged is Clicked else Page close clicked
  if (IsTrue == 0) {
    BTGUI.WebServices.ConnectionToken.GetLogOutClientUserMethod(LogOutClientUserMethodSucess);
  }
  else {
    BTGUI.WebServices.ConnectionToken.PageClosedXmlMethod(hddClient, hddUserName);
  }
```

`Bind()` or `on()` events are not firing in IE 10,Except IE working all browsers fine. any IE version this will work
I'm using jquery 1.7.0
I'm also tested `$(window)` not working.

Comment: Does live() work? Even though it's deprecated.

Comment: yes it's working.Except IE window close.

Comment: Might want to try using a more current version of jQuery; the latest 1.X release is 1.11.1: http://jquery.com/download/#jquery-1-x

Comment: yes .i did tested all jQuery version. not working

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the event handler should be bound to $(window). A beforeunload handler is supposed to only return a string to be displayed in a confirmation box. It seems to me that you're doing a lot more than that.

Comment: Actually if return any string it's popup confirm box. I don't need popup box. for popup for only giving IE .other browser won't.